How to apply OLS with constraints on coefficients and align the output scale with the target variable?
I am working on an OLS regression problem where:
The dependent variable (target) ranges from 1 to 6 (with steps of 1).
The independent variables range from 1 to 10 (with steps of 0.5).
I want to set up the model such that:
There is no intercept.
The sum of all coefficients (β) is equal to 1.
The output aligns with the scale of the dependent variable (1 to 6).
However, when all independent variables are at their maximum value of 10, the model output scales up to 10, which is outside the target range. I can't scale the independent variables. I can scale the depended variables. So, that it is 1 to 10. But is there any other way? How can I adjust my OLS setup?
I’d appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to implement this.
